# Track Lead Status values on a Lead

Tags: apex, visualforce, administration

I have a custom field('Marketing Lead Status pick list (A, B, C, D)') on Lead. When I am inserting lead from web Marketing Lead Status set to 'A' and when lead inserted manually Status needs to set 'B' and When Lead is converted to opportunity with status A, B, C Status field needs to update D, When Lead is converted to Opportunity with Status D; no needs to do any action.

Please suggest me to proceed on this. Thank You in advance.
(Not sure we can use trigger code or workflow rule).

Regards
venkat.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look in the Help under [Create Multiple Business Processes](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_multiple_business_processes.htm&langua_1). If this is a picklist, your business process would define which values are available for each type of process, profile and recordtype.

Your Marketing Users would only be able to create leads for Campaigns using Status A, other users could only use Status B. Not certain what Status C represents, but as you said, upon conversion to opportunity & account, the lead is updated to Status D during Conversion which honestly, is something of a waste of time since you'll not see the lead again since it becomes closed. But that's beside the point.

Comment: Hi,
Thank You! :) for your response.
One point adding for above information. I am using custom convert for lead convertion. Hence, Lead is available even we converted the lead to opportunity and account.

Comment: There's a lead conversion class that one can implement. If I understand your comments, that's not what you're actually doing. It sounds like instead, you're keeping your leads open and archiving them or something similar. Thanks for posting on SFSE. Community etiquette is to upvote well thought out questions and answers if you have sufficient reputation plus help the rest of the community by marking posts as solving your question if they helped you resolve your issue.